# ¿Cómo hacer que el texto quede en el centro del círculo?

Tags: java, pdf, itext

Estoy intentando imprimir círculos en un pdf con iTextPdf, ya consigo imprimirlo, rellenarlo y ponerle un borde de otro color, solo me falta crear un texto o una letra e insertarlo en el centro de éste, tengo este código, pero el resultado no es el esperado. ¿Alguien podría colaborarme a centrar el texto?. Adjunto código

```
String ruta = "hello.pdf";
    PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(ruta);
    PdfDocument doc = new PdfDocument(writer);
    doc.addNewPage();
    PdfCanvas circle = new PdfCanvas(doc, 1);
    Color rose = new DeviceCmyk(5, 40, 20, 0);
    Color blue = new DeviceCmyk(70, 0, 95, 0);
    circle.circle(doc.getDefaultPageSize().getWidth() / 2, doc.getDefaultPageSize().getHeight() - 20 - 2, 20).setColor(rose, true).setStrokeColor(blue).fillStroke();
    PdfFont font = PdfFontFactory.createFont(StandardFonts.HELVETICA);
    Text title1 = new Text("The Strange Case of ").setFontColor(ColorConstants.BLUE);
    circle.resetFillColorCmyk();
    circle.resetStrokeColorCmyk();
    circle.beginText();
    circle.setFontAndSize(font, 10);
    circle.setColor(blue, true);
    circle.fillStroke();
    circle.setTextMatrix(doc.getDefaultPageSize().getWidth() / 2, doc.getDefaultPageSize().getHeight() - 20 - 2);
    circle.showText("H");
    circle.endText();
    doc.close();
```

Adjunto el resultado
[image: Ejemplo de impresión en pdf]

Comment: relacionado: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/413545/imprimir-un-c%c3%adrculo-con-texto-con-itextpdf-java